# essential information?

Tags: commas

> Before a vaccine was finally discovered by an American **scientist Jonas Salk** in 1955, more than 80% of polio patients received help from the foundation.

I was given options of a) keeping the bold part as it is or b) changing it to "**scientist, Jonas Salk,**". I had chosen a) without hesitation, but apparently, b) is correct. However, I don't understand why because isn't Jonas Salk an essential information here?

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, the original version is wrong.

The use of a pair of commas would make it nonessential information and work with the indefinite article.

To demonstrate:

> . . . by an American scientist, Jonas Salk, in 1955 . . .
>    . . . by an American scientist in 1955 . . .

The name adds information to the sentence, but it is not a requirement to the sentence structure.

---

To make it essential information, there should be no commas but there should also be no indefinite article (either the definite article or no article at all):

> . . . by the American scientist Jonas Salk in 1955 . . .
>    . . . by American scientist Jonas Salk in 1955 . . .

---

*Essential information*, in this sense, is a grammatical phrase. If *you* think that the name of the scientist is essential to the meaning you want to convey, then you should not be putting the name inside a pair of parenthetical commas. (However, in this case, that wasn't one of the possible answers.)

Answer (score 0):

In your example, yes, "***Jonas Salk***" is essential information, but it's a modifier of "***American scientist**", so

> by an American scientist, Jonas Salk, in 1955,

BTW, since a specific American scientist is being spoken about, it might be better as

> by **the** American scientist Jonas Salk in 1955,

You can also think of it this way

> by Jonas Salk, an American scientist, in 1955,

Comment: "the American scientist, Jonas Salk, in 1995" would be incorrect, because it sounds like Jonas Salk is the one and only American scientist. In this case it's a nonrestrictive clause and you'd drop the commas.

Comment: @mamster  If one says "David Cameron, **the** former UK Prime Minister" it does not mean he is the *one and only* former UK Prime Minister.

Comment: You've reversed the order of the clauses. In this case, "the former UK Prime Minister" is the non-restrictive clause. It distinguishes him from "David Cameron, the gas station attendant," and so on.

Comment: Also, the use of the definite article complicates things a lot. "The American scientist" is very different from "American scientist" or "An American scientist" with regards to how the following clause should be punctuated.

Comment: Oh, and "The American scientist, Jonas Salk, ..." could be fine if you had been talking about two scientists, an American and a Tanzanian, and wanted to focus on the American one.

Comment: @mamster you are being very dogmatic here - and I do not believe you. It is just not true that formulations such as "The British writer, H. G. Wells, was famous for..." imply that Wells was the only British writer, not least because as any fool knows there are more than just one British writer, American scientist etc. If there is only one of something then you must use 'the'; but if there are well known to be many then 'the ' can be used.

Comment: Here's what I'm saying: as one native American English speaker, "The British writer, H. G. Wells," is ungrammatical to me. If I were an editor, I'd flag it. This is really getting into the realm of prescriptivism, but punctuation often lives in the prescriptivism realm. You're right--it's not a big deal.